# CAP theorum is applicale for Replication or Sharding?

Tags: sql, nosql, rdbms, partitioning, cap-theorem

I went through [CAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) . After going though it, my understanding is CAP makes sense only in context 
of replication (where write happens on one node i.e. Master and then replicated across slaves) not for sharding/horizontal scaling(where data is
partitioned based on some key. So different data lies on different nodes).

Ideally data will be always be consistent/available in shards(mainly NoSql DB)
as single node contains required data and there is no need to write the same data to other node. So in NoSql there is no need to be
parttion tolerant as there  is node of communication between node until and unless replication is required. So why CAP theorum comes into picture for NoSql DB where sharding
is used not replication.

To me choosing b/w C and A should makes sense where we are using replication not shard which mainly happens in SQL DB not in NOSql DB  but reading the articles on google primarily talks about NoSql DB's in terms of CAP

I know I am missing something as CAP theorum but not sure what it is ?

Comment: CAP gives limits on how a user interface can behave given that it has a distributed implementation. You are not clearly distinguishing between the user interface & its implementation. Replication & sharding can be part of either. The CAP always applies, it says user failure to acces data means either interruptions or inconsistencies. It has nothing to do with SQL vs NoSQL. SQL systems can have user-visible replication, sharding etc & even running SQL not in SERIALIZED transaction mode reflects CAP consequences. PS Read lots of presentations.

Comment: PS If a user only ever uses a local node then you don't need to apply CAP. But if a user can access non-local shards then CAP applies; non-local access could fail. There needn't be replication for that.

Comment: @philipxy shard  keeps independent/partitioned data which it does not need to communicate to another shard. So even network failure between nodes will not impact. So CAP does not come into picture here.

Comment: I repeat, all that matters, and the definition makes this clear, is accessibility/locality, and presence or absence of replication and/or sharding alone doesn't tell you anything. Eg f every user had a local node that is partitioned into some unique data for each user then there is no replication but there can be failure. You also seem to incorrectly assume that replication and/or sharding can only be used in certain limited ways in SQL & NoSQLs.

Comment: @philipxy I'm not sure what you mean here, but disregarding the noSQL part, I think emilly is right. The CAP theorem is doesn't say anything in particular about distributed systems; what it says is that when partition fault tolerance is needed, there is generally a tradeoff between availability and consistency.

In practice, partition fault tolerance is achieved through replication. Having replication means that different nodes in the network will need to synchronize to achieve consistency, which takes time, hence the availability/consistence tradeoff.

Comment: In theory, although stupid, you could have a partitioned database (sharding) without any kind of replication. If there is no replication, there is no availability/consistency tradeoff because there is nothing to synchronize between nodes. Having a distributed database is not a "requirement" for the CAP theorem; it is implied as a side effect of replication to achieve partition fault tolerance.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that CAP theorem does not apply if there is only a single master for each shard (without any type of replication). But most implementations have a master shard **plus** one, two or more slaves for read only queries. And this configuration repeats for each shard in the cluster. Then, there is replication hence CAP theorem applies (and [PACELC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PACELC_theorem) theorem applies). The replication can be for scaling the shard but mostly for availaibility. If the master shard fails, one of the other takes the master role.